# Linq query to find duplicate objects based on multiple fields AND property is null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to locate duplicate objects based on 2 fields but ONLY where a 3rd field is also null

```
ItemNumber, Name, Pricebook, Parent
Item1, A, B, <null>
Item2, A, B, Item1
Item3, A, B, <null>
Item4, A, B, Item1
Item5, A, B, Item2
```

So in the above list the only 2 duplicate items are effectively Item1 and Item3

```
var duplicateItemsList =
    from i in items
    group i by new { i.ItemNumber, i.Pricebook, i.Parent } into d
    where d.Count() > 1
    select new { ItemNumber = d.Key.ItemNumber, Pricebook = d.Key.Pricebook, Parent = d.Key.Parent, Count = d.Count() };
```

The trouble I am having is working the check for the null field value in the Linq query.

After the above Linq query I just want to end up with a list containing the duplicated ItemNumber and Pricebook field values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need `Parent` property in result and in groping key, because it will have `null` value. Also you don't need to specify property name for anonymous object if it is same as name of assigned property.

```
var duplicateItemsList =
    from i in items
    where i.Parent == null
    group i by new { i.Name, i.Pricebook } into d
    where d.Count() > 1
    select new { 
                  d.Key.Name, 
                  d.Key.Pricebook, 
                  Count = d.Count()
               };
```

Also you can introduce new range variable to store items count in group. Then items count will be calculated only once:

```
var duplicateItemsList =
    from i in items
    where i.Parent == null
    group i by new { i.Name, i.Pricebook } into d
    let groupItemsCount = d.Count()
    where groupItemsCount > 1
    select new { 
                  d.Key.Name, 
                  d.Key.Pricebook, 
                  Count = groupItemsCount
               };
```

*UPDATE* as @Blachshma pointed, you have grouping by ItemNumber instead of Name

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I did try running your code and got 0 results. I think it is because you are grouping on `ItemNumber` instead of `Name`

Comment: @Blachshma agree, grouping should be by `Name` and `Pricebook` - I just copy-pasted that part from question

Comment: @Woodjitsu grouping by `ItemNumber` should not work for you, because it will create five different groups with keys like `{Item1, B}, {Item2, B} etc`. What you really need is key `{A, B}`

Comment: Either way, the accepted answer is incorrect also. @Woodjitsu - I'm guessing you incorrectly wrote the order of the names of your columns in the question. In your question you wrote that `ItemNumber` is the first column (which holds "Item1", "Item2", ...) and grouping by that will always give 0 results.

Comment: Agree - Currently the only correct answer is @lazyberezovsky's

Comment: Blachsma - Yep - just checked that and realised what I had done in the question and had the columns names around the wrong way (itemnumber and name).  Won't update question columns however as then that throws out @lazyberezovsky's (corrected) answer code

Comment: Changed selected answer to suit the original question asked

Answer (score 2):

```
var duplicateItemsList =
    from i in items
    where i.Parent == null
    group i by new { i.ItemNumber, i.Pricebook, i.Parent } into d
    where d.Count() > 1
    select new { ItemNumber = d.Key.ItemNumber, Pricebook = d.Key.Pricebook, Parent = d.Key.Parent, Count = d.Count() };
```

You can filter only the null items before you group and do your duplicate check with an additional where clause.

Comment: Cheers Kevin,  Figured this one out myself after a but more playing around with it and came up with the same solution - Cheers tot the prompt reply. I was originally trying to filter in the 2nd where clause after the grouping which was obviously wrong