# Find same properties value fields using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have following classes in my VB.NET project.

```
Public Class Field
       Public Property FieldName As String
       Public Property ScriptObject As Script
End Class

Public Class Script
       Public Property ScriptName As String
       Public Property InputParamList As List (Of InputParam)
       Public Property OutputParam As String
End Class


Public Class InputParam
       Public Property ParamName As String
       Public Property Type As String //Type can be Field, FixValue or Counter
       Public Property FieldName As String
       Public Property FixValue As String
       Public Property CounterObject As Counter
End Class

Public Class Counter
       Public Property StartValue As Integer
       Public Property StepValue As Integer
End Class
```

One of my business function returns me `List(Of Field)`. From `List(Of Field)`, I need to filter/find Fields which have same Script configuration means has same script name, has same input parameter configuration(Name,Type,FieldName,FixValue,and also counter configuration (StartValue,StepValue)).

How can I achieve this using LINQ query or via EqualityComparer or any other way ?

**EXAMPLE**

**==================**

Below are sample functions. `GetFields()` function returns `List(of Field)` from that I need `List(Of Field)` which has same `ScriptObject` configuration(same properties value). In below `GetFields()` function FirstField and SecondField have same ScriptObject in terms of Script Name, InputParam Properties. So, I want `IGrouping(of String,List(Of Field))` (ScriptName ('Script1') as string and List(Of Field) which has First and Second Field item) from `List(Of Field)` returns by `GetFields()` by using LINQ or any other way.

```
Public Function GetFields() As List(Of Field)
    Dim oFieldList As New List(Of Field)
    Dim oFirstScript As Script = GetFirstScript()
        Dim oSecondScript As Script = GetSecondScript()


    Dim oFirstField As New Field
    oFirstField.Name = "FirstField"
    oFirstField.ScriptObject = New Script()
    oFirstField.ScriptObject.Name = oFirstScript.Name
    oFirstField.ScriptObject.InputParamList = new List(Of InputParam)

    For Each oInParam In oFirstScript.InputParamList
        Dim oInputParam = New InputParam()
        oInputParam.Name = oInParam.Name
        oInputParam.Type = oInParam.Type
        oInputParam.FixVaue = oInParam.FixValue
        oInputParam.CounterObject = oInParam.CounterObject  
        oFirstField.ScriptObject.InputParamList.Add(oInputParam)
    Next

    oFirstField.OutputParam = oFirstScript.OutputParam

    oFieldList.Add(oFirstField)

    //Second Field
    Dim oSecondField As New Field
    oSecondField.Name = "SecondField" 
    oSecondField.ScriptObject = New Script()
    oSecondField.ScriptObject.Name = oFirstScript.Name
    oSecondField.ScriptObject.InputParamList = new List(Of InputParam)

    For Each oInParam In oFirstScript.InputParamList
        Dim oInputParam = New InputParam()
        oInputParam.Name = oInParam.Name
        oInputParam.Type = oInParam.Type
        oInputParam.FixVaue = oInParam.FixValue
        oInputParam.CounterObject = oInParam.CounterObject  
        oSecondField.ScriptObject.InputParamList.Add(oInputParam)
    Next

    oSecondField.OutputParam = oFirstScript.OutputParam

    oFieldList.Add(oSecondField)

    //Third Field
    Dim oThirdField As New Field
    oThirdField.Name = "ThirdField" 
    oThirdField.ScriptObject = New Script()
    oThirdField.ScriptObject.Name = oSecondScript.Name
    oThirdField.ScriptObject.InputParamList = new List(Of InputParam)

    For Each oInParam In oSecondScript.InputParamList
        Dim oInputParam = New InputParam()
        oInputParam.Name = oInParam.Name
        oInputParam.Type = oInParam.Type
        oInputParam.FixVaue = oInParam.FixValue
        oInputParam.CounterObject = oInParam.CounterObject  
        oThirdField.ScriptObject.InputParamList.Add(oInputParam)
    Next

    oThirdField.OutputParam = oSecondScript.OutputParam

    oFieldList.Add(oThirdField)

    Return oFieldList
End Function

Public Function GetFirstScript() As Script
    Dim oScript As New Script
    oScript.Name = "Script1"
    oScript.InputParamList = New List(Of InputParam)

    Dim oFieldInputParam As New InputParam
    oFieldInputParam.Name = "Param1"
    oFieldInputParam.Type = "Field"
    oFieldInputParam.FieldName = "FirstField"
    oFieldInputParam.FixValue = String.Empty
    oFieldInputParam.CounterObject = Nothing

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oFieldInputParam)

    Dim oFixInputParam As New InputParam
    oFixInputParam.Name = "Param2"
    oFixInputParam.Type = "FixValue"
    oFixInputParam.FieldName = String.Empty
    oFixInputParam.FixValue = "123"
    oFixInputParam.CounterObject = Nothing

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oFixInputParam)

    Dim oCounterInputParam As New InputParam
    oCounterInputParam.Name = "Param3"
    oCounterInputParam.Type = "Counter"
    oCounterInputParam.FieldName = String.Empty
    oCounterInputParam.FixValue = String.Empty
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject = New Counter
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject.StartValue = 1
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject.StepValue = 1

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oCounterInputParam)

    oScript.OutputParam = "returnResult"

    Return oScript
End Function

Public Function GetSecondScript() As Script
    Dim oScript As New Script
    oScript.Name = "Script2"
    oScript.InputParamList = New List(Of InputParam)

    Dim oFieldInputParam As New InputParam
    oFieldInputParam.Name = "Param1"
    oFieldInputParam.Type = "Field"
    oFieldInputParam.FieldName = "SecondField"
    oFieldInputParam.FixValue = String.Empty
    oFieldInputParam.CounterObject = Nothing

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oFieldInputParam)

    Dim oFixInputParam As New InputParam
    oFixInputParam.Name = "Param2"
    oFixInputParam.Type = "FixValue"
    oFixInputParam.FieldName = String.Empty
    oFixInputParam.FixValue = "XYZ"
    oFixInputParam.CounterObject = Nothing

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oFixInputParam)

    Dim oCounterInputParam As New InputParam
    oCounterInputParam.Name = "Param3"
    oCounterInputParam.Type = "Counter"
    oCounterInputParam.FieldName = String.Empty
    oCounterInputParam.FixValue = String.Empty
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject = New Counter
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject.StartValue = 1
    oCounterInputParam.CounterObject.StepValue = 1

    oScript.InputParamList.Add(oCounterInputParam)

    oScript.OutputParam = "returnResult"

    Return oScript
End Function
```

Note: ScriptName is unique. So it's not possible that same script name ScriptObject have different input parameter count and param name. only type of parameter can be different.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the output to be. An example would be very helpful.

Comment: I need List(Of Field) as output which have same ScriptObject(Name, InputParamList). I am preparing example. So, will attach with question soon.

Comment: The same ScriptObject *as what*? The list could have multiple "groups" of equivalent fields.

Comment: I guess, this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561376/linq-query-to-find-duplicate-objects-based-on-multiple-fields-and-property-is-nu

Comment: @JonSkeet added sample example functions in question.

Comment: @JigneshThakker: But what would you want to happen if you had a *fourth* field which was the same as the third?

Comment: I think IGrouping(of String,List(Of Field)) result will be better fit for this type of scenario. So, I want result type as IGrouping of ScriptName, List(Of Field).

Comment: ScriptName is unique. So it's not possible that same script name ScriptObject have different input parameter count and param name. only type of parameter can be different.